# Passing additional parameters to an Apps Script event object

Tags: google-apps-script, callback, gmail-addons

I'm having a lot of headaches with callbacks and scopes in Apps Script. I have the following function, that creates a Gmail Add-On section with a checkbox for each attached file on the currently open email:

```
function createAttachmentsSection( attachments ){

  var widget = CardService.newSelectionInput()
    .setFieldName( 'selectedFiles' )
    .setType( CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX )
    .setOnChangeAction(
      CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName( 'checkboxAltered' )
    );

  for ( var i = 0 ; i < attachments.length; i++ )
    widget.addItem( attachments[i].getName(), '' + i ,  true )

  return CardService.newCardSection().addWidget( widget );
}
```

Everything is displayed as expected, but I want the user to be also able to select which files he wants to uncheck for later processing.
In my checkboxAltered function I want to handle user selection input actions, which is the only way to go (as far as I've learned from the documentation. Please tell me if I'm wrong!). It's currently an empty function, only used to check how little I understand:

```
function checkboxAltered( e ){

  Logger.log( e );
  Logger.log( selections.length );
}
```

`e`, the event object, is always `undefined` here. And `selections`, a (previously initialized and checked) global bool array with an item for each attachment, is always simply `[]` inside checkboxAltered.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I use setParameters( Object ) to tell inside the callback function which checkbox was clicked by the user?
Are global variables not accessible from callback functions?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the CardService documentation the [`Action`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action) class has a [`setParameters()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action#setParameters(Object)) method. If you want to pass custom parameters to the callback you'll need to use that method.

Comment: Now solved. I still have no idea though what was causing the event object to be empty, but now it's not, and I can access its additional parameters without problems.
Also, the array `selections` was always empty because every time a callback function is called the script is executed from scratch, in a completely new context, which I didn't know before.

Comment: Both the key and value of object passed to Action.setParameters() should be a string. I stringified and passed the event object created by contextualTriggers even then it's throwing an error. I need to access the event object to extract attachment information in another card. Any idea?