# How to tell if SelectionInput checkbox is checked or not in callback?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

How can you tell if a SelectionInput checkbox item is checked in a callback? I have the following:

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput()
                .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
                .setFieldName("chkSaveAttachments")
                .addItem("Save Attachments", "chkSaveAttachmentsValue", true));
```

I have a button on my card that triggers a callback. From the callback, all I can access is the value ("chkSaveAttachmentsValue") but I can't tell whether the box is checked or unchecked.

```
function saveCallback(e) {
  Logger.log(e.formInput.chkSaveAttachments); //prints "chkSaveAttachmentsValue"
  Logger.log(e.formInput.chkSaveAttachments.chkSaveAttachmentsValue) //undefined
  Logger.log(e.formInput.chkSaveAttachments.chkSaveAttachmentsValue.selected) //undefined
}
```

Comment: If you use Stackdriver to log (via `console.`), what do you get? You can often interact with the structure there ( or at least access it for more than a single execution).

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48733462/passing-additional-parameters-to-an-apps-script-event-object) discusses a similar problem. While the only answer refers to [`.setParameters`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action#setParameters(Object)) OP is unclear whether this solved the problem. You might give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the state of checkbox by looking at the formInput in the onChange callback.

```
CardService.newSelectionInput()
            .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
            .setFieldName("chkSaveAttachments")
            .addItem("Save Attachments", "chkSaveAttachmentsValue", true).setOnChangeAction(selectionAction)

var selectionAction = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("selectionAction").setParameters({"obj": obj});

function selectionAction(e) {
    //formInput value comes only when it is selected.
    var selected = !!e.formInput.chkSaveAttachments;
    // you can set and access paramters in the onchange action for further use.
    if(selected) {
    // cache the state using cacheservice
    } else {
    // cache the state using cacheservice
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't realize the e.formInput.chkSaveAttachments is null when the checkbox is unchecked. I don't need to use the cache at all, I can just use !!e.formInput.chkSaveAttachments in the button save callback and it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/actions#action_event_objects), **formInputs** property would be helpful here.

> For multi-valued widgets such as checkboxes, you can read each value from **formInputs** instead.

In formInputs, all the selected options will be there in an array(e.formInputs.chkSaveAttachments).
Hence, in your `saveCallback` function, you can check as

```
e.formInputs.chkSaveAttachments.indexOf('chkSaveAttachmentsValue') > -1
```